# Subclass PyOpenSSL X509 and initialize it with existing certificate

Tags: pyopenssl

My question is if it possible to create a `X509` subclass like the following to provide some utility methods (e.g. one method to retrieve the serial number in hex format instead of as a number):

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import X509


class MyX509(X509):
    def get_serial_number_hex(self):
        return hex(self.get_serial_number())
```

And initialize it later from a existing certificate, for example:

```
my_x509 = MyX509(cert_as_pem_string)
```

Now, I've tried that approach but I can't find an appropriate constructor/method in the parent `X509` that allows for initialization from an existing certificate.